# Querying ManyToManyTable In Django

Tags: django, orm

Given the following model, I'm trying to generate a data set that will get the quantity field from OrderItems while also getting the other columns from Item and Order.  I'm trying to write the query in Django's ORM but have been having issues.

```
 class Order(models.Model):

    items = models.ManyToManyField("Item", through="OrderItems")
    order_date = models.DateTimeField()
    
    
class Item(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    orders = models.ManyToManyField("Order", through="OrderItems")
    

class OrderItems(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey("Order", null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    item = models.ForeignKey("Item", null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
```

The query I've tried:

```
Order.objects.prefetch_related('items').filter(id=order_id)
```

That will get me the Items for the order, but I can't figure out how to get the quantity field.

Comment: In that case you `prefetch_related('orderitems_set', 'orderitems_set__item')`, and you iterate over the `.orderitem_set`. This is thus the collection of related `OrderItem`s.

Answer (score 0):

@William Thank you for your response - if you post it as the answer I'll tick it accordingly.  I was missing that those objects are also available in prefetch_related.